# two barchart and one linechart in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have two barcharts and one linechart in one plot using ggplot.

I checked the following code, but did not work

```
 df1<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(10,20,30,24,44))
 df2<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(9,25,22,24, 25))
 df3<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(10,20,30,24,44))

  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y), stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())+
 geom_bar(data=df2, aes( y=y), stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ 
 geom_line(data=df3, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Abbas

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked now. But the only problem is that the barcharts are stacked but I liked to be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need to be putting 'data =.., x=..etc' in ggplot and then + the geom_bars and lines.

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

e.g.

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked now. But the only problem is that the barcharts are stacked but I liked to be grouped.

Comment: without the code it is difficult for me (a newbie) to help much more, others may be able to without it but are likely to want your question to be worded better.

Comment: library("ggplot2")
  df1<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(10,20,30,24,44))
  df2<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(9,25,22,24, 25))
  df3<- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(10,20,30,24,44))
  
  ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(), fill="blue",colour="blue")+
    geom_bar(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),fill="red",colour="red")+ 
    geom_line(data=df3, aes(x=x, y=y))

Comment: This is the code I wrote regarding your comment. of course I added colours to the barcharts.

Comment: do you need three different datasets? for the 2 barcharts at least could you not include an extra variable instead to separate them and then use that value to group and colour them?

Comment: Thanks. Actually these are the set temperature and mean  and max measured temperature in five steps of a reaction in a oven mixer. Maybe I have to add one more variable such as step: 1:5 for grouping. I will try that and  will let you know.

Comment: I checked the code and it did not work. In addition I prefer to have the data separated. Do you have any other idea to handle the data in this condition and make a grouped barcharts?

Comment: you should probably ask a new Q if you have a new problem (i.e. grouped barcharts)